# Custom Module accessible to other users but not working properly

Tags: magento2, module, adminhtml, magento2.4, custom

I have created a custom module named "Service voucher list"
I have created the acl.xml file too so that other users can have its access by custom resources too. now the module is accessible there, but the other user is not able to redeem the vouchers, it is showing some error on the page, i will attach the screenshot of the same
at console i am getting "403 forbidden" error for grid/grid/redeem/

screenshot of the error
[image: screenshot of the error]